# How to update a StateProvider when disposing a widget?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

If I try and update the `stateProvider` by overriding the widgets `dispose` method I get an exception as shown below. Any idea how to update the state, so that the next time this widget is rebuilt it's using the state of null:

Code:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  //reset any request map initial bounds
  ref.read(fsdMapStateProvider.notifier).state = null;
  super.dispose();
}
```

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `deactivate` method rather than the `dispose`.

This method gets called before the widget is removed from the widget tree, meaning just before the widget gets fully disposed.

```
@override
void deactivate() {
  //reset any request map initial bounds
  ref.read(fsdMapStateProvider.notifier).state = null;
  super.deactivate();
}
```

Docs: [deactivate method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/deactivate.html)

Comment: From the docs: "Called when this object __is removed__ from the tree"